# SQL bit type versus PHP conditions

Tags: php, sql, types, bit

Today I run into one bug. I have few columns in my DB with `BIT` type. I am getting those values (0/1) And when I tried to compare it in short if statement I got always false.

```
$cat->is_visible = ($cat_vis == 1) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

This result in FALSE even when the $cat_vis got 1 in DB. Any ideas why is it so ?

Comment: And what does `var_dump($cat_vis);` show? Are you sure you are assigning this value to correct variable?

Comment: Well when I was running it at wamp - localhost it was working okay even with the bit version. the var_dump outputs: `string(1) ""`

Comment: to rule out syntax issues, would standard if / else behaviour be same?

Comment: Youre apprently not getting the values since `$cat_vis` is an empty string.

Comment: There's absolutely no point in a ternary operator here - `($cat_vis == 1)` will return a boolean anyway.

Comment: Here is my screen from DB. THere is only simple query and I am getting all the values expect those BIT ones http://prntscr.com/1jh7zz

Comment: `$cat_vis` is not empty, it contains one character (to see what it is, run `ord($cat_vis)` to get its ascii value). Your problem seems to be in place when you are querying DB and assigning row to variables. Can you show the code for it?

Comment: well thanks for your time and interest but I was talking also with support of my hosting and they werent able to help me. I changed the datatypes of those columns to tinyint(1) so I can store 1/0 there and it will be ok. Once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have issues trying to compare the `BIT` type directly.  What happens if you cast the field in the query?

e.g.

```
SELECT `is_visible`+0 AS is_visible FROM cat;
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(`is_visible` AS UNSIGNED) AS is_visible FROM cat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit are referred with b'1' or 'true/false' or binary notation.Try query using bit notation

```
SELECT cols FROM tablename WHERE bit_column = (1)
```

then refer it.

Comment: Well I think you don't understand. I have query to get data from table. Then I want to set my variables `$cat->is_visible` (TRUE/FALSE) and this variable depends on the value which I get from the select

Comment: I do understand , paste output of


echo "gettype($cat_vis) == gettype(1)";

Comment: gettype of variable = string, gettype of 1 = int; and the echo of that code: gettype() == gettype(1)

Comment: your $cat_vis is not containing 1. please check query for retrieving that

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get to this point as well. My query is OK and working at loclahost, it is not working on my webhost

Comment: :) What should I tell you for that ? I told earlier in comments under question that var_dump of that variable contains empty string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$cat->is_visible = ($cat_vis === '1') ? true : false;
```